# magento2 - how to redirect to 404 page

Tags: magento-2.1, controllers, redirect

The requirement is to redirect to 404 page when data passed on URL query string is not correct. So in the controller, I get the data from URL and check if it is correct, it can proceed. And What should I do when it is incorrect, it should redirect to 404 page?

Answer (score 10):

There are some methods discussed on different forums but the one worked for me is as follow.

```
<?php

namespace Company\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    public function execute() {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Parameter is incorrect.'));                 
    }
}
```

This will throw an exception and return a 404 not found page.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code for redirect to 404 page all pages, It is working definitely.

All page redirect 301 with PHP code.

http://code.wewebtech.com/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-all-pages-using-htaccess/

Comment: Not related to Magento 2